# Let $X$ be a random variable and $P(X<u)\leq \Phi (u)\leq P(X\leq u)$ for all $u$. Is X a continuous random variable?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X$ be a random variable and $P(X<u)\leq \Phi (u)\leq P(X\leq u)$ for all $u$. Everything is defined on the real line and $\Phi(\cdot)$ is standard Normal.

Is X a continuous random variable and $F_X(u)=\Phi(u)$?

---

My intuition tells me that this is true. Graphically, $F_X$ is always right continuous and if $\Phi(u)\neq P(X\leq u)$ then there would be a contradiction by increasing $u$ by an epsilon amount.

---

**(Follow-up questions, edited material)**

How would you prove it?

My attempt:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \Phi(u-\frac{1}{n})\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  P(X<u)\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \Phi (u)\leq\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  P(X\leq u)\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \Phi(u+\frac{1}{n})$$

Thus,

$$\Phi(u)\leq P(X<u)\leq\Phi(u) \leq P(X\leq u)\leq\Phi(u)\ \blacksquare$$

Can you guys provide an alternative way to prove it?

Comment: Yes - since $\Phi(u)$ is continuous and strictly increasing, so invertible

Comment: I think you need to define your notation.  If $\Phi$ is an arbitrary function, then obviously the answer is No.  If it's the cdf of the standard normal, the answer is yes.  If it's something else, who knows....

Comment: Can you prove it and write it in the answer? Ideally, not the one I provied unless my solution is wrong.

Comment: There seem to be some typos in the string of inequalities following "My attempt:"  It looks like you're on the right track, though.

Comment: @PeterMorfe Would you point them out precisely?